# "Native" (-vs- 3rd party) browser push notifications for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'd love to have browser push notifications added to my Wordpress site like those offered by https://www.producthunt.com/

At the moment, I can only find plugins/services like OneSignal.com. You can see this in action @ http://steve.doig.com.au/ - the red bell icon at bottom right.

Is there a Wordpress solution that asks the visitor if they want to subscribe to notifications using the browser's (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari) notification protocol (like at producthunt.com), rather than going through a 3rd party icon that visitors may be unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProductHunt uses OneSignal actually. Since their website is HTTPS-only, they are able to use certain customizations that are not available for HTTP sites. This limitation is related to how Web Push is built into browsers.

These customizations are as follows:

1. On HTTPS websites, users can subscribe to notifications directly on that site's domain. On HTTP sites, OneSignal uses a workaround so that users are subscribed under a `https://yoursite.onesignal.com`domain instead.
2. On HTTPS websites, users can be auto-prompted to opt-in to notifications.
3. On HTTP sites, autoprompting is not possible so OneSignal has an optional notify button that is placed on your website that users can click to opt-in. ProductHunt disables the OneSignal notify button since they use autoprompting instead.

OneSignal's documentation has an overview of the different features available to HTTPS vs HTTP sites here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/http-vs-https-features